# How do I achieve this using a flatMap

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

I need to create a new inner List and use that to set the outer list. How can I do using the flatMap. fooList is a list of FooDb object from which I create list of Foo object.

```
final ArrayList<FooDb> fooList= getFooFromDB();    
final ArrayList<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
            fooList.forEach(foo -> {
                final ArrayList<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<>();
                item.getItems()
                    .forEach(item -> bars.add(new Bar(foo.getId(), foo.getName())));
                foos.add(new Foo(0L, foo.getId(), bars));
            });
```

Comment: do you mean, that you have Foo class that has list of Bar's class? Because in your example is not clear what itemsList (foos?) means. Could you please provide structure of that classes?

Comment: what is `itemsList`? what are further `item.getItems()`? the code shared wouldn't compile for the occurrence of `item` as a variable in different contexts.

Comment: Achieve what? Please edit your title to be complete, and summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `flatMap`. You have two `map` operations:

1. `List<Item> -> List<Foo(..., ..., List<Bar>)>`, and
2. `List<Item> -> List<Bar>` which is required for the former.

---

```
List<Foo> foos = 
    itemsList.stream()
             .map(item -> new Foo(0L, item.getId(), item.getItems()
                                                        .stream()
                                                        .map(i -> new Bar(i.getId(), i.getName()))
                                                        .collect(Collectors.toList())))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

<sup>Terrible formatting, I've been working with Stream API for a few years now and never could write a good-looking chain. Feel free to edit.</sup>

Comment: the first and the second transformation would mostly have different source unless the entity is something like `class Item { Collection<Item> items;...}`

Comment: @Naman it's highly likely `getItems()` returns a `List<Item>`. Let's see what the OP will say

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a FlatMap to do it. FlatMap tipically must be used to flattenize the content of an array. In this case you want a 1 to 1 mapping so the right way is a Map Function.

```
itemsList
.stream()
.map(item -> new Foo(0L,item.getId, item
                                    .getItems()
                                    .stream()
                                    .map(item -> new Bar(item.getId(),item.getName())).collect(toList())));
```